# Android alarm queue not meeting times

Tags: android, alarm

I do not understand why I can not create alarm manager queue. Once the first alarm, the others follow in cascade not meeting times.
Here's the code that will be called when click "Start" button:

```
final AlarmManager[] alarmManager=new AlarmManager[50];    
Integer i =0;
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmSMS.this, 
                                         MyAlarmService.class);

            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmSMS.this, i, 
                                                     myIntent, 0);

             thatDay.set(dataPick.getYear(), dataPick.getMonth(),dataPick.getDayOfMonth(), timePicker1.getCurrentHour(), timePicker1.getCurrentMinute());

            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

            long diff = (thatDay.getTimeInMillis()- calendar.getTimeInMillis());

            int sec =   (int) (diff / 1000 % 60);

                      calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND,sec);//Sec it's the difference between time selected and now
          alarmManager[i] = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
          alarmManager[i].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
                      calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);


           i++; 

}
```

Comment: How can we help you if you don't show us how you are working with `calendar` or when `onClick()` is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting all of your alarms to occur at `calendar`'s time, I'm guessing that you meant to use `thatDay`:

```
alarmManager[i].set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, thatDay.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

---

I have a couple notes:

- There is only one AlarmManager, so `alarmManager` contains up to 50 copies of the same system service.
- Your index `i` is dependent on the users actions, you could have less or *more* than fifty alarms. You should use an ArrayList and `add()`.